# Excel w/vba Program not coming to foreground at PC start Windows10 touchscreen

Tags: excel, vba, touchscreen

I have a windows10 pc with a touchscreen and no keyboard or mouse. I have an excel program that I want to start up everytime the pc is restarted. I used shell:startup to place a shortcut for the file in the folder and the system will start and open the file but it is in the background. I can click it from the tablet menu and it opens but i would like it to come to the foreground by itself. I did some testing and setup the exact same file into a nontouch screen laptop and the file opens perfect. Here is a sample of the simple vba code running on the file and some code I have tried to make it come to the foreground.

```
private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.Caption = "Test System"

    Application.Wait (Now + 0.0001)

    'SendKeys "%{Tab}", True

    'ActiveWindow.Visible = True

    MsgBox "System Restarting", vbcritcal + vbSystemModal

End Sub
```

the two comment lines I have tried to make the program come to the foreground but they did not help, I tried them one at a time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
restartct = Sheets("search").Cells(1, 13)
If GetTickCount < 80000 Then
  restartct = restartct + 1
  Application.Wait (Now + 0.0001)
  Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
  frmBadinput.Label1 = "System Restarting"
  SendKeys "%{tab}"
  mdelay = 2
  frmBadinput.Show
End If
frmWelcome.Show
 Sheets("Search").Activate
 ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 13).Value = restartct
 ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1).Select
 ActiveWindow.Zoom = 120
End Sub
```

Macro#1
`Option Explicit  Public Declare Function GetTickCount& Lib "kernel32" ()`

I used a few forms also and some other variables to track pc system restarts

Answer (score 0):

`AppActivate` will do the job for you like so:

`AppActivate ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption`

You said that this was happening right after a restart, so `ThisWorkbook.Windows` should only have that 1 member in it.  Alternatively, you can give the name of the window to the command like this:

`AppActivate "Book1 - Excel"`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried to use AppActivate thisworkbook.windows(1).caption and only received a runtime error #5. I also tried using a varible and setting it to activewindow but still received runtime error #5 ended up with the following to finally work. I used a variable in the macro#1 to determine time since startup so the steps only work during a reboot. I tried putting the sendkeys command in a few spots but it only ended up working after some other code ran.